# What should I do to get the process status by pid?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

I tried `process.kill(pid, 0)` to get the status, but got

```
node:internal/process/per_thread:221
      throw errnoException(err, 'kill');
      ^

Error: kill ESRCH
    at process.kill (node:internal/process/per_thread:221:13)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\demo\web.js:7:43)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  errno: -4040,
  code: 'ESRCH',
  syscall: 'kill'
}
```

A total of two executions. It returned true for the first time, then set the timer to get it again, and returned error.

> This method will throw an error if the target pid does not exist. As a special case, a signal of 0 can be used to test for the existence of a process. Windows platforms will throw an error if the pid is used to kill a process group.

From the above, if the process does not exist, `process.kill(pid, 0)` should return false instead of an error. Could it be that `0` is not only a check, but also kill?

Comment: That's not my interpretation. `0` just tells it not to actually kill the process (or rather, not to send a signal). Otherwise it behaves the same: throws an exception if the process doesn't exist. The docs don't list a return value for any case.

Comment: @Ouroborus Does that mean I can use `error.code == 'ESRCH'` to tell if a process doesn't exist?

Comment: From the docs "This method will throw an error if the target pid does not exist." So you don't even need to check that closely, just see if the call triggered an exception. (If you're on Windows, their might be a different exception if you tried to kill a process group. The exception code still probably doesn't matter since, despite its name, `process.kill` just sends a signal. The exception happens when it fails to do so.)